# Google Places API key not working

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

For testing my Google Places key, I ran a simple web address in chrome: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=50.6483,70.129&radius=2&types=train_station&key=myKey

The result was: 
{

```
"debug_info" : [],
```

"html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"

}

I generated another key from API console, but that also didnt work. I have enabled Google Places in Servies tab of API Console. I checked other questions. This is a common question. Is there any solution yet? I have been using the same key 4-5 months back. It was working. The same link worked 4-5 months back, but now the link is not working, even tried with many different keys

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue is probably best handled by raising on our issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/